# Inline block element, not inline in this case

Tags: html, css

I have set my search bar `div` element as `inline-block`, as well as the `img`.

However, the `div` element is below the image, instead on the same horizontal line.

Anyone can advise me why this is happening?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
#header img {
  height: 56px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#search {
  display: inline-block;
}
#search input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 584px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
#search input:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="http://orig04.deviantart.net/1d83/f/2013/087/5/6/google_icon_by_slamiticon-d5z7lrp.png" />
  <div id="search">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your styles are working as they should; the `#search input` element's width is just too wide! Try looking at the result on a wider screen, and you will see the elements appear inline as expected.

Anticipating your next question, you can prevent wrapping of inline elements using the rule (on the container, e.g. `#header`):

`white-space: nowrap`

Anticipating your **next** question (if I may be so bold), you will probably want to set CSS rule:

`vertical-align: middle`

on both `#header img` and `#search` to get the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet with what you want. The problem here is width of input. Since its more it bring the div to next line.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
#header img {
  height: 56px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#search {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -22px;
}
#search input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 480px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
#search input:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="http://orig04.deviantart.net/1d83/f/2013/087/5/6/google_icon_by_slamiticon-d5z7lrp.png" />
  <div id="search">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The total width of image and search input is greater than full width of screen. Try with lesser width either of image or search input.
try this one

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    #header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    #header img {
      height: 56px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #search {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      top: -22px;
    }
    #search input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 450px;
      height: 38px;
      border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    }
    #search input:hover {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
      <img src="http://orig04.deviantart.net/1d83/f/2013/087/5/6/google_icon_by_slamiticon-d5z7lrp.png" />
      <div id="search">
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="search" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```